# trouble deploying helloworld project in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, cmd, pycharm

I am following a very simple tutorial for google app engine and at a point, after having installed Google sdk for python, it is asked to deploy the hello world app using the command from windows CMD:

```
>dev_appserver.py helloworld
```

My problem is: when I type this command, my Pycharm automatically pop up and open a tmp folder containing `dev_appserver.py`, as if I wanted to edit the file. I think that, when pycharm is installed, it forces a redirection of every command of the form `>test.py` to open the corresponding file in pycharm instead of executing the command.

What can I do to get rid of this?

Comment: Shouldn't that command be `>python dev_appserver.py helloworld` ?

Comment: I don't think so because it's a command, not a file I have to run.

Comment: I know, it is strange to have commands ending by .py but this is how it goes for Google SDK in python.

Comment: Dimitris Jim is correct; it doesn't matter if it's a "command" or not, since Windows has messed up your file associations typing "python" first will work.

Comment: Yes but I have to place my cmd in my Google SDK. I would really prefer to fix this file association problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the file association problem means removing the `.py` file association (likely created at pycharm's installation), which depends on your Windows version.

[This official suggestion](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/17717edb-daa2-4e7f-adb2-c277d4619d46/how-to-delete-file-association-with-an-unwanted-program-i-dont-want-it-associate-with-any?forum=w7itprogeneral) can be applied to several Windows versions.

For alternate solution search for "file association remove delete" and your Windows version, plenty of advice out there.

Note: after removing the association you'll need to manually select the application to use when you actually want to edit a `.py` file (which is not a big deal for one which typically opens the files from pycharm project windows).